# Query of MongoDB with Java driver not executing properly

Tags: java, mongodb

I am performing MongoDB search operation with Java in Eclipse.

Code for MongoDB operation:

```
 public ServerResponse checkUsername(String username) throws UnknownHostException, MongoException {
        Mongo mongo = null;
        DB db = null;
        DBCollection vendorCollection = null ;


        mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        db = mongo.getDB("Database_Name");
        vendorCollection = db.getCollection("Collection_Name");
        int i = 0;

        int uId=0;
        System.out.println("Username"+username);
        BasicDBObject inQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        inQuery.put("user_name",username);
        //inQuery.put("user_name","12345");

        DBCursor cursor = vendorCollection.find(inQuery);
        if (cursor.hasNext()) {
            BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
            userName += obj.getString("user_name");
            serverResponse.setVendor_id(obj.getInt("_id"));
            //System.out.println(userName+":Exist");
            serverResponse.setExist("true");
            System.out.println(userName+"::"+serverResponse.getExist());
            return serverResponse;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(username+":Not Exist");
                serverResponse.setExist("false");
                System.out.println(userName+"::"+serverResponse.getExist());
                return serverResponse;
            }
}
```

This is simple code for executing simple search operation.Now here I am passing **username** variable to this function and checking for whether it is exist or not,here thought it is exist in collection it is not able to find this so going in else condition,Strange thing that,as showing in commented line when I insert **username** value **hard-coded** it is finding it from collection.

before some days it was working perfectly,not getting why this is happening,even I cleaned Project too.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @BlakesSeven if inserting user_name value hard-coded only then it is successfully searching.as shown in comment

Comment: Well, note that the "hardcoded" value is a string. The variable you are passing in likely is not. Dont forget that `.println()` calls `.toString()` on the objects it is passed.

Comment: @BlakesSeven so what should i do ? and let me tell you before some days it was working properly without hardcoded value.

Comment: Check "everything". Either 1. Input, 2. Database name, 3. Collection. Also that `int uid=0` does not appear to reference anything, which makes it supect why it was there in the first place. There is no problem with the code ( though I would not be connecting to the database every time this was called ) that you show here really. That only leaves the other variables that might not be doing what you expect. Just spoke to someone else here who was running two `mongod` instances. Make sure you are not doing the same as well.